# bouncycastle throws exception when file contains a mix of secret and public keys

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg

I am running this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PGPException {
    InputStream privateKeyRings = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/secring.gpg");
    PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSecretKeyRings =
        new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(privateKeyRings),  new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing found where PGPSecretKeyRing expected
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:36)
```

Therefor I inspected the file secring.gpg by running

```
gpg --show-keys --no-default-keyring secring.gpg
```

Which gives me a list of keys

```
sec#  rsa4096 2013-02-21 [SC]
      37B...
uid                      xyz <xyz@xyz.com>
ssb#  rsa4096 2013-02-21 [E]

sec#  rsa4096 2013-02-14 [SC]
      22C...
uid                      abc <abc@abc.com>
ssb#  rsa4096 2013-02-14 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2013-04-19 [SC]
      5A1...
uid                      def <def@def.com>
sub   rsa4096 2013-04-19 [E]
```

So as far as I can tell, the file contains secret keys, except for the last entry which seems to be a public key.

So my guess is that this is causing the error.

What is the best way to avoid the error?

Do I need to remove the public key from the file secring.gpg? If so, what is the command for this?

And is there another way to handle this scenario in the java code?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes that class supports only secret key 'rings'](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPSecretKeyRingCollection.java#L47) (note what Bouncy calls a 'keyring' is what GnuPG just calls a key, and what GnuPg calls a keyring is what Bouncy calls a 'collection').

I think the best way is indeed to fix the file. That file name `secring.gpg` was used by older versions of GnuPG for a file in OpenPGP format that contained only secret keys, not public, so whoever created that file either did something really weird and wrong or was trying to mislead and harm people. I don't think there ever was a command that could fix a public key in secring because that wasn't supposed to happen in the first place. In any case modern GnuPG no longer uses that file; it now uses a *directory* containing separate files in a libgcrypt-based format.

What you could do is use GnuPG to `--import` this file (import can handle both secret and public keys, because *interchange* can in various cases use either) and then `--export-secret-keys` the desired ones. If you set env var GNUPGHOME to a new (empty) directory and import to that, you can simply export everything valid from that directory and then delete it.

Alternatively you could write your own class which is *like* `PGPSecretKeyRingCollection` but ignores (skips) any `PGPPublicKeyRing` object(s). If the rest of your code, or any code you call to use this data, only uses the behavior of `PGPSecretKeyRingCollection` and doesn't depend on internals or exact identity -- which by OO doctrine it shouldn't -- you can just substitute your object. In older Java you can even `extends` the real class, so that it can be stored in variables etc. declared with the real type, but with recent Java (9 up) I think subclassing across modules is restricted and this may require `--add-opens` or somesuch -- I haven't looked into that area yet.

More ambitiously, Bouncy is opensource, so you could fork it and make this change, and any others you want. Of course you would need to set up a complete build environment for it, and periodically take at least the upstream changes that either provide new features you need or want or are security fixes -- in practice it's almost certainly easier to take all changes, and if something conflicts cross that bridge when you get to it.